# How to store images using Entity Framework Code First CTP 5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, ef-code-first

I'm just trying to figure out if there is a simple way to store and retrieve binary (file) data using EF Code First CTP 5? I would really like it to use the FILESTREAM type, but I'm really just looking for some way to make it work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can't use SQL `FILESTREAM` in EF. EF is supposed to work on top of different database servers but filestream feature is specific feature of SQL 2008 and newer. You can try to do it old way - use `varbinary(max)` in your database table and use byte array in your mapped class.

**Edit:**

Little clarification - you can use `FILESTREAM` in the database but EF will not take advantage of streaming. It will load it as standard `varbinary(max)`.

Answer (score 123):

I always create another class like `ProductImage` with a one-to-one association in order to manage lazy loading and also to normalize the table:

```
public class ProductImage
{
    public int ProductId { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to create a view that doesn't include the file image column and then create a second entity in EF that points to the view instead of the table - say, e.g. "ProductLite"

Comment: @C.List I can't believe I have been using EF for years and never thought of doing that.  It's a fabulous idea and I just put it to use, getting rid of an unnecessary view that I was using to do the same thing. Let's call it a "virtual entity" :)

Answer (score 71):

Just declare your property as byte[] as Ladislav mentioned.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte[] ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

That is pretty much it. If you don't map the property the convention is it maps to a `varbinary(max)`.
If you have an image column in the database already just add `[Column(TypeName = "image")]` on the ProductImage property or if you prefer code mapping add this to your OnModelCreating override in the context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(p => p.ProductImage).HasColumnType("image");
```

The problem I have with it is that I have not found a way to make the property lazy as I don't necessarily want to load binary data every time I fetch a product.
I not sure I recall correctly but NHibernate can do it out of the box.

Comment: Yes, NHibernate can do the column-specific lazy-loading out of the box: http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.